# Reading data from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to apply a join operation on 2 nodes in firebase database. How will       I do this?

Following is the structure of my database :

I have two nodes : user node and books node 
I want to traverse books node and For every book I need to find every user's name (available in user node) who like that book .
I need to make an array of such names and display it in recycler view.
Is there any function which will trigger when all the data will be fetched?
    Here is my code:

```
  DatabaseReference bookRef;
bookRef.addOnSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener ){
  @Override
  public void OnDataChanged(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
    //I will get userReference fromdatasnapshot
    DatabaseReference userReference ;
    userReference.addOnSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener ){
      @Override
      public void OnDataChanged(DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
              //Add Username in arrayList

          } 
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: Nested listener will be called inside a loop which will iterate on book node

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `HashMap<>` for storing the likes of user which like the book inside the book node then you will have no need to travrse through the user node you can get the value of like `Hashmap` and set as recycle view or what you want

Comment: Thanx for upvote you can also get code for this through  [firebase quickstart on github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/fragment/PostListFragment.java) on line88 hope this will help more